# how to regexp_extract before nth occurance hive

Tags: regex, hive, hiveql

I have string like this:

```
LLC1R.8888.GR0054656*DR.798012...2..............GR0054656*EUR*
```

I already make extraction with this:
`REGEXP_EXTRACT(b.COLUMN_YY,'^([^\.]+)\.?',2)`

but it occur with error 2 : mapredtask

```
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:157)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to execute method public java.lang.String org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpExtract.evaluate(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer)  on object org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpExtract@5875de6a of class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpExtract with arguments :java.lang.String, ^([^.]+).?:java.lang.String, 2:java.lang.Integer} of size 3
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.invoke(FunctionRegistry.java:1024)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDFBridge.evaluate(GenericUDFBridge.java:194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator._evaluate(ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluator.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 2
```

what went wrong and how it should be fixed?

Any help/ideas will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clear what went wrong from the error stack trace: "*Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: **No group 2***"

See [`REGEXP_EXTRACT` reference](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions):

> Returns the string extracted using the pattern. For example, `regexp_extract('foothebar', 'foo(.*?)(bar)', 2)` returns `'bar.'` Note that some care is necessary in using predefined character classes: using `'\s'` as the second argument will match the letter `s`; `'\\s'` is necessary to match whitespace, etc. The `'index'` parameter is the Java regex *Matcher* `group()` method index. See [docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) for more information on the 'index' or Java regex `group()` method.

So, to get the first substring before `.`, you should use

```sql
REGEXP_EXTRACT(b.COLUMN_YY, '^([^.]*)', 1)
```

To get the second string between `.`, use

```sql
REGEXP_EXTRACT(b.COLUMN_YY, '^[^.]*\\.([^.]*)', 1)
```

To get the nth string between `.`, use `(?:[^.]*\.){n-1}`. So, to get the third one, use

```sql
REGEXP_EXTRACT(b.COLUMN_YY, '^(?:[^.]*\\.){2}([^.]*)', 1)
```

Note that `1` *index* argument makes `REGEXP_EXTRACT` return the value captured in Group 1, see the pattern details below:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^.]*\.){2}` - here, two occurrences of

  - `[^.]*`  - 0 or more chars other than `.`
  - `\.`  - a `.` char
- `([^.]*)` - **Group 1**: any 0 or more chars other than `.`.